# yii2 many to many where clause

Tags: mysql, yii2, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation in Yii2 and I want to set where clause but frameworks says : Unknown column!

here is my find code :

```
 $rm = ProductHasAttValue::find()
                ->with('attValue')
                ->where('product_id='.$id." AND attValue.att_id=1") 
                ->all();
```

I'm truly sure the  attValue's table has a column  with name :att_id.

why should I set this where correctly  ?

thanks in advance ?

p.s:
if I don't use that where clause and write this foreach I can get the att_id values ..

```
foreach($rm as $ziizii){

            echo $ziizii->attValue->att_id."*";

}
```

model :

```
here is my whole modle class :<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "att_value".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $att_id
 * @property string $value
 *
 * @property Att $att
 * @property ProductHasAttValue[] $productHasAttValues
 * @property Product[] $products
 */
class AttValue extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'att_value';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['att_id', 'value'], 'required'],
            [['id', 'att_id'], 'integer'],
            [['value'], 'string']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'att_id' => 'Att ID',
            'value' => 'Value',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAtt()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Att::className(), ['id' => 'att_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProductHasAttValues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductHasAttValue::className(), ['att_value_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['id' => 'product_id'])->viaTable('product_has_att_value', ['att_value_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In where clause it shouldn't be

```
->where('product_id='.$id." AND attValue.att_id=1")
```

But

```
->where('product_id='.$id." AND att_value.att_id=1")
```

You should replace the relation name `attValue` with related table name in where clause

Comment: where is the relation name :

Comment: public function getProductHasAttValues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductHasAttValue::className(), ['att_value_id' => 'id']);
    }

Comment: Now Im confused , can you tell the Modal Class Name and corresponding table names in your relation

Comment: Also this `->with('attValue')` .....  where is this relation defined , can you share that code as well ??

Comment: I paste the whole model in the qoustion :

Comment: ->with('attValue') worked , and I think so attValue is my relation name

Comment: and this line worked too  echo $ziizii->attValue->att_id.

Comment: It will work. I have made a change to my answer , what i meant was to replace the `attValue` (Relation Name)  in Where Clause to `att_value` (Table Name)

Comment: not work too ! Unknown column 'att_value.att_id' in 'where clause'
 it should be work but why !!

Comment: You have many to Many relation ryt ?? so ProductHasAttValuehas Many AttValue. This AttValue.att_id has nothing to do with the relation , its a condition for joined att_value table , am i right ??

Comment: @kiamoz glad to help :)